# vm.$set(...) or defining the object parameter from the start ... What's better?

Tags: json, vue.js

I have a JSON array in which I can dynamically add a simple property to its objects (visible:false) with Vue.set, like this :

```
this.$set(object,'visible',false);
```

If an object of the array needs to be visible (which the case most of the time), it just doesn't have this property. I did this because my JSON array can be REALLY big and I didn't want to have this "useless" property.

My question is : is it a good practice according to Vue.js ? I saw in the documentation that Vue.set is kind of a hack for setting properties. Does this hack influence reactivity of Vue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vue core dev here.

`set()` is not a hack, it's a necessary extra step you need to go to add properties that should be reactive.

We advise having all properties on our objects during definition, but the reason for this is mainly that we feel it's better for our app's maintainability if you have the shape of your data clearly defined in one place.

You won't pay a noticable performance hit or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :)